# Edit controller asp.net MVC (using enity framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

[image]I am having some trouble with my "edit view". I can create new items and view them no problem.
I also can enter the edit form and view everything and change. But for some reason It won't accept my form on the date, even though it is the same date as I used to create the entry.

my edit controllers are as follows:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            News news = db.News.Find(id);
            if (news == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(news);
        }

        // POST: /Newss/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="ID,title,body,category,dateCreated")] News news)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.Entry(news).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(news);
        }
```

My edit view is as follows:

```
@model NewsFeed.Models.News

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>News</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.title, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.title)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.body, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.body)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.body)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.category, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.category)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.category)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dateCreated, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dateCreated)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dateCreated)
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Edit**

Model:

```
public class News
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is Required")] 
        public string title { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Body is Required")] 
        public string body { get; set; }
        public Category category { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }


        public enum Category 
        {
            Sports,
            News,
            Politics,
            Education
        }
```

Comment: `It won't accept my form on the date` what does this mean exactly?

Comment: I get the message: "The field dateCreated must be a date"

Comment: See the edit in my OP

Comment: looks like you have a `DataType.DateTime` attribute on your dateCreated property

Comment: Question might not be relevant, but why are you using `EditorFor` instead of `TextBoxFor`?

Comment: It seems there is a problem with the culture setting. Please check the  culture of your code using CUltureInfo. Then set the proper culture for your setting and then date should accept

Comment: Can you show your Model?

Comment: I have updated my post. Now you can see my model

Comment: Hi @user3265963 since jQuery is performing the validation, you will need to teak the code to parse the Date correctly, but it is easier to use a jquery date Picker when creating the date

Answer (score 0):

Change `datetime` to `nullable`, it should work. This was what worked on my project.